# How can I change the content-type of an object using AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface, aws-cli, content-type

I've got several objects stored in Amazon S3 whose content-type I need to change from `text/html` to `application/rss+xml`. I gather that it should be possible to do this with a copy command, specifying the same path for the source and destination. I'm trying to do this using the AWS cli tools, but I'm getting this error:

```
$ aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/feed/ogg/index.html \
            s3://mybucket/feed/ogg/index.html \
            --content-type 'application/rss+xml'
copy failed: s3://mybucket/feed/ogg/index.html
to s3://mybucket/feed/ogg/index.html
A client error (InvalidRequest) occurred when calling the
CopyObject operation: This copy request is illegal because it is
trying to copy an object to itself without changing the object's
metadata, storage class, website redirect location or encryption
attributes.
```

If I specify a different path for source and destination, I don't get the error:

```
$ aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/feed/ogg/index.html \
            s3://mybucket/feed/ogg/index2.html \
            --content-type 'application/rss+xml'
copy: s3://mybucket/feed/ogg/index.html
to s3://mybucket/feed/ogg/index2.html
```

Even though the command completes successfully, the `index2.html` object is created with the `text/html` content type, not the `application/rss+xml` type that I specified.

How can I modify this command-line to make it work?

Comment: Just saw [this issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/652#issuecomment-41213226) reporting the same problem. That thread includes a couple of workarounds, so I'll see how I get on with them.

Answer (score 19):

It's possible to use the low level `s3api` to make this change:

```
$ aws s3api copy-object --bucket archive --content-type "application/rss+xml" \
    --copy-source archive/test/test.html --key test/test.html \
    --metadata-directive "REPLACE"
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/copy-object.html

The problem was just not being able to specify the `--metadata-directive`. Thanks for pointing out the [open issue / feature request](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/652), nelstrom!

Comment: How can this be executed for several objects with a certain extension?

Comment: There may be a cleaner way, but you could list the object in a file then read all the lines and execute the above command on each line, so the above would look like:

`while read line; do copy-object --bucket archive --content-type "application/rss+xml" --copy-source archive/$line.html --key $line.html --metadata-directive "REPLACE"; done < objects.txt`

Answer (score 10):

You can also do it with the higher level API, by copying a file over itself but marking it as a change in metadata:

```
aws s3 cp \
  --content-type "application/rss+xml" \
  --metadata-directive REPLACE \
  s3://mybucket/myfile \
  s3://mybucket/myfile
```

Answer (score 3):

You can override the **content-type** of your file, with the `aws s3 cp` command, using the `--metadata-directive` optional attribute to specify the content-type is replaced with the one provided with `--content-type 'application/rss+xml'` during the copy:

```
aws s3 cp \
--content-type 'application/rss+xml' \
--metadata-directive REPLACE \
s3://mybucket/feed/ogg/index.html \
s3://mybucket/feed/ogg/index.html
```

More information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

Then, you can verify it by checking the file metadata:

```
aws s3api head-object \
--bucket mybucket \
--key feed/ogg/index.html
```