# Change the default content type on multiple files that have been uploaded to a AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

Using aws-cli I uploaded 5gb of files to an Amazon S3 bucket that I have made a static website. Some of the files the site references are .shtml files, but S3 has defaulted to a metadata content type of `binary/octet-stream` but I want those files to have a metadata content-Type of `text/html`. Otherwise it doesn't work in the browser.

Is there a aws-cli s3api command I can use to change the content type for all files with a .shtml extension?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set content type on specific file types like the following.

```
"aws s3 sync ${BASE_DIR} s3://${BUCKET_NAME} --exclude *.shtml"
"aws s3 sync ${BASE_DIR} s3://${BUCKET_NAME} --exclude '*' --include '*.shtml' --no-guess-mime-type --content-type text/html"
```

Comment: Why do you have the first line mentioning .svg?

Comment: What does BASE_DIR refer to?

Comment: Updated to be pertinent to the OP's question. BASE_DIR would be your file's location.

Answer (score 3):

To modify the metadata on an Amazon S3 object, **copy the object to itself** and specify the metadata.

From StackOverflow: [How can I change the content-type of an object using aws cli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548256/how-can-i-change-the-content-type-of-an-object-using-aws-cli):

```
$ aws s3api copy-object --bucket archive --content-type "application/rss+xml" \
    --copy-source archive/test/test.html --key test/test.html \
    --metadata-directive "REPLACE"
```