# S3 Images being downloaded automatically when linked

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What permission am I missing or is this something else ?

We are using S3 for storage and to serve images to a site with moderate traffic.
We built out a custom thumbnail slider that links a small thumbnail image to a larger slider image at different resolution.

Before S3 came into play the images would link to each other. Now once the thumbnail is clicked that image is downloaded automatically rather than just linking to the larger image. Any thoughts?

Here is the code, but this is just an S3 question really. Thanks!

```
<div class="thumbnails" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">
    <ul id="easy-slide">
      <i id="prev" class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      {thumbnails}
      <li itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <a href="{thumbnails:large}" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="500x500">
          <img src="{thumbnails:thumb}" height="100px" width="100px" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
        </a>
      </li>
      {/thumbnails}
     <i id="next" class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Do the images have the correct MIME type? image/jpeg or image/png and so on? If not you need to change or reupload with the new MIME type

Comment: Is there a way to set that for an entire folder or a bucket policy ? I'm not sure on how to check that.

Comment: Check to be sure. Use `curl -I -v http://www.example.com/image.jpg` and confirm the `Content-Type`

Answer (score 2):

Likely a Content-Type problem. The correct MIME type is not being set when you uploaded the images to S3.

Just to confirm, check the MIME type being returned:

```
curl -I -v http://www.example.com/image.jpg
```

Then you will need to set the correct content type in the S3 metadata. To update the the metadata on the S3 object, you can copy the object to itself, and specify the content type on the command line.

From [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548256/how-can-i-change-the-content-type-of-an-object-using-aws-cli): How can I change the content-type of an object using aws cli?:

```
$ aws s3api copy-object --bucket archive --content-type "image/jpg" \
    --copy-source archive/test/image.jpg--key test/image.jpg \
    --metadata-directive "REPLACE"
```

To answer your question:

> Is there a way to set that for an entire folder or a bucket policy?

S3 does not actually have folder/directories. You need to touch each object via CLI to change its content type.  See [What is the difference between Buckets and Folders in Amazon S3?](https://serverfault.com/questions/435827/what-is-the-difference-between-buckets-and-folders-in-amazon-s3). But the command I referenced below will do that operation on an entire bucket.

So you will need to use the S3 CLI to update the content type metadata. Here is another answer showing the a variety of command line methods, that will change all the content type for all files of a given type (E.g. png), recursively:

```
aws s3 cp \
      --exclude "*" \
      --include "*.png" \
      --content-type="image/png"  \
      --metadata-directive="REPLACE" \
      --recursive \
      --dryrun \
       s3://mybucket/static/ \
       s3://mybucket/static/
```

See https://serverfault.com/questions/725562/recursively-changing-the-content-type-for-files-of-a-given-extension-on-amazon-s

Comment: Thanks for the input. But the content type is already set to image/png. Any other ideas ?

Comment: Interesting.  How are you confirming the Content-Type? Just wondering., Also, can you include a link to an image?

Comment: curl -I -v http://s3.amazonaws.com/dpec/assets/images/homepageads/36-6020_5_hero_large.png

Comment: Hm that image renders perfectly in the browser. Content-Type: image/png.  Does this image have the download problem?

Comment: Sorry that one doesn't have the download prob. but this one does http://s3.amazonaws.com/dpec/assets/images/products/tablesaws/36-6020/small/36-6020_vw13_small.png I see the content type is wrong. can I set the content type for a certain folder path. Meaning all images in this folder have this content ?

Comment: Cool thanks. Well you have two problems. #1 When uploading the file, the content type is not being set correctly.  Fix that asap.  #2 Fix objects that have the incorrect content type. I suggested a solution above. I suggest you try it - that is the solution.  There is no way to do it at the 'folder' level. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

When uploading using the API, the default content type is attachment.

Sending a request using the content type parameter solves the problem. Include the "ContentType" parameter in the header request as below:

```
{
    Bucket: <BUCKET NAME>, 
    Key: "", // pass key
    Body: null, // pass file body,
    ContentType: "image/jpg, image/png, image/jpeg"
}
```

The URL generated after uploading this way would allow browser access instead of an automatic download.

Answer (score 0):

here i use AWS SDK For PHP And my code like

```
$certificateImageName=$_FILES['uploadCertificate']['name'];
  $certificateImageTmp=$_FILES['uploadCertificate']['tmp_name'];
  $certificateImageType=$_FILES['uploadCertificate']['type']; 

  $certificateImageName=$engineerDetails['id'].date("Y-m-d-s",time()).$certificateImageName;
if($certificateImageType == "image/png" || $certificateImageType == "image/jpg" || $certificateImageType == "image/jpeg" || $certificateImageType == "image/gif" || $certificateImageType == "application/pdf"){
    try {
      // Upload data.
      $uploadResult = $s3->putObject([
        'Bucket' => $bucketforCertificate,
        'Key'    => $certificateImageName,
        'SourceFile' => $certificateImageTmp,
        'ContentType' => $certificateImageType, //You have to set contenttype else when you access it download the file  
        'ACL' => 'public-read'
      ]);
  
      // Print the URL to the object.
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    }  
<your data insertion code >
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).